# Solving combinatorial problems with symbolic method and generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions, combinatorial-proofs, analytic-combinatorics

I am trying to solve the following problems:

a) Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of all finite 0-1-sequences that have no 1s directly behind each other. Let the weight of each sequence be its length. 
How can $\mathcal{F}$ be constructed with simpler objects? How does the generating function look like?

b) Show with generating functions: The number of partitions of n into different summands equals the number of partitions of n into odd summands.

c) Show with generating functions: The number of compositions of n into summands being 1 or 2 equals the number of compositions of n+2 into summands greater than or equal 2.

My solutions:

a) I have no idea here.

b) Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the partition in different summands. Then $\mathcal{P} = (\{\epsilon\}+\{1\}) \times (\{\epsilon\}+\{2\})\times (\{\epsilon\}+\{3\})\times ...$

$\Rightarrow P(z) = (1+z)\cdot (1+z^2) \cdot (1+z^3) \cdot \dotsc = \frac{1}{(1-z)\cdot(1-z^3)\cdot(1-z^5)\cdot \dotsc}$

Now let $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}$ be the partition in odd summands. Then $\tilde{\mathcal{P}} = \{1\}^{\ast}\times\{3\}^{\ast}\times\{5\}^{\ast}\times\dotsc$

$\Rightarrow \tilde{P(z)} = \frac{1}{1-z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-z^3}\cdot\frac{1}{1-z^5}\cdot \dotsc$.

Therefore $P(z) = \tilde{P}(z)$ and so $[z^n]P(z) = [z^n]\tilde{P}(z)$, which proofs that the numbers of partitions of n are the same.

c) Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the number of compositions of n into 1s and 2s. 
Then $\mathcal{K} = \{1,2\}^{\ast}$ and so $K(z) = \frac{1}{1-(z+z^2)}$.

Let $\tilde{\mathcal{K}}$ be the number of compositions of n+2 into 2,3,4,5,6,7,... Then $\tilde{\mathcal{K}} = \{2,3,4,5,6,...\}^{\ast}$ and therefore $\tilde{K}(z) = \frac{1}{1-(z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+...)}$.

I am not sure if I have determined $\mathcal{K}, \tilde{\mathcal{K}}, K(z)$ and $\tilde{K}(z)$ correctly and if so, I don't know how to show that $[z^n]K(z) = [z^{n+2}]\tilde{K}(z)$.

So I'd very much appreciate your help on a) and c). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused about (c). There are two compositions of $2$ into ones and twos: $1+1$ and $2$. There is only one composition of $4$ into threes or more: $4$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks for your comment, you are right, I made a mistake. It should say "greater than OR EQUAL 2". I will correct it, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that there are no adjacent ones is *almost* equivalent to saying that every $1$ is followed by a $0$. In that case, the string is freely built out of copies of $0$ and $10$, so this is $\{0,10\}^*$. However, there is also optionally a $1$ at the end which is not followed by a zero, so it is more like $\{0,10\}^*\times \{\varepsilon,1\}$.

---

Let $k_n$ be the number of compositions of $n$ into $\{2,3,4,\dots\}$. What you found is 
$$
\frac1{1-(z^2+z^3+\dots)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty k_n x^n=\tilde K(z)
$$
It is probability easier to find
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty k_{n+2} x^n=K_2(z)
$$
Then, all you have to do is prove that $K_2(z)=K(z)$, which is simple algebra.

You are almost done! Can you see how to easily get $K_2$ from $\tilde K$?

Note 
$$
K_2(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty k_{n+2}x^n=\sum_{n=2}^\infty k_nx^{n-2}=\frac1{x^2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty k_nx^n
$$
The last summation almost looks like $\tilde K(z)$. The only problem is that the summation starts from $n=2$, not $n=0$. Therefore, the summation $\sum_{n=2}^\infty k_nx^n$ is attained from $\tilde K(z)$ by subtracting the first two terms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am going to try to solve it with the information you gave and let you know if it worked. :)

Comment: @Studentu Sure! Just to clarify, $K'(z)$ does not refer to the derivative of $K(z)$, it is just a new function.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I indeed thought you meant the derivative. But now I don't know how to find K'(z). I only can think of $\mathcal{K'}$(z) being equal to $\tilde{\mathcal{K}}(z)$, which is probably wrong and would yield what I already have...?

Comment: @Studentu See edit for more details. I changed $K'$ to $K_2$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll have another look at c). For a) I got now the generating function: 
$\mathcal{F} = \{0,10\}^{\ast}\times\{\epsilon, 1\} \Rightarrow F(z) = \left(\frac{1}{1-(z^1+z^2)}\right)\cdot(z^0+z^1) = \frac{1-z^2}{1-2z+z^3}$, since the generating function of $\{0,10\}$ is $z^1+z^2$ and the generating function of $\{\epsilon, 1\}$ is $z^0+z^1$. (At least I think they are.)

Comment: @Studentu Looks good!

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I think your Edit should make the solution obvious, but I still don't find it. We get $K_2(z)$ from $\tilde{K}(z)$ by subtracting $0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot z$ from $\tilde{K}$ and dividing the result by $z^2$, so $K_2(z) = \frac{1}{z^2} \cdot \frac{1-z}{1-z-z^2}$. But this doesn't equal K(z)? 
I think, I need some more help. please.

Comment: @Studentu Very subtle error! You need to instead to instead subtract $\color{red}1\cdot 1+0\cdot z$ from $\tilde K$. Because of the empty composition, $k_0=1$. This now [works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Fz%5E2)(K_2-1)+%3D+1%2F(1-(z%2Bz%5E2))+where+K_2+%3D+1%2F(1-(1%2F(1-z)-1-z))).

Comment: You are right, it worked just fine now! :) 
But why is $k_0$ = 0, i.e., why does the empty composition have weight 1? (I mean, in the example of the 0-1-sequence, $\epsilon$ did have weight 0 due to the definition of the weight... Is there a general rule for when the empty thing is defined with weight 0 and when with weight 1 or else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91414/discussion-between-mike-earnest-and-studentu).

Answer (score 3):

> Ad    c.)
>
> Your           approach          is    fine. With ${\mathcal{K}} = \{1,2\}^{\ast}$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> K(z) &= \frac{1}{1-\left(z+z^2\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> and with $\tilde{\mathcal{K}} = \{2,3,4,5,6,...\}^{\ast}$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \tilde{K}(z) &= \frac{1}{1-(z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+\cdots)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{1-z}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1-z}{1-z-z^2}\\
> &=1+\frac{z^2}{1-z-z^2}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2)  we use  the   *[geometric    series  expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.

> We obtain from (1) and  (3) for $n\geq 1$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^{n+2}]\tilde{K}(z)} &=[z^{n+2}]\left(1+\frac{z^2}{1-z-z^2}\right)\\
> &=[z^{n+2}]\frac{z^2}{1-z-z^2}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[z^n]K(z)}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In  (4) we skip the term $1$  which does not contribute to the coefficient of $z^{n+2}$ since $n\geq 1$.
- In (5) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.

> Note  the coefficients of 
>   \begin{align*}
> K(z)&=\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}\\
> &=\color{blue}{1}+\color{blue}{1}z+\color{blue}{2}z^2+\color{blue}{3}z^3+\color{blue}{5}z^4+\color{blue}{8}z^5+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   are  the *[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)*.

ad   a.)

We  start    with binary   sequences with *no consecutive* equal characters at all. See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick for more information.

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a binary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left.\left(1-\frac{u}{1+u}-\frac{w}{1+w}\right)^{-1}\right|_{u=w=z}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

where  $u$ represents occurrences of $0$ and $w$ occurrences of $1$.
Since there  are  no restrictions stated for  zeros we replace occurrences of $0$ in a Smirnov word by one or more zeros. 
\begin{align*}\
u\longrightarrow u+u^2+u^3+\cdots=\frac{u}{1-u}\tag{7}
\end{align*}

> We substitute (7) in (6) evaluate at $z$ and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{\frac{z}{1-z}}{1+\frac{z}{1-z}}-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}
> &=\left(1-z-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\\
> &=\frac{1+z}{1-z-z^2}\\
> &=1+2z+3z^2+5z^3+8z^4+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> which is again  a generating function of (shifted) Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially for the one regarding a), and for the link to the reference to the book! :)

Comment: @Studentu: You're welcome. :-)